# unloading a view in app delegate

Tags: iphone, memory, uiviewcontroller

I have the following delegate files. My AboutViewController in MainWindow.xib loads the AboutViewController.xib and the aboutViewController outlet is connected to it. Also, navController is loaded from another ViewController.xib.
AboutViewController's view is displayed at start up and removed after one second, so i release its view controller by setting the ivar to nil.

As the about view controller is loaded by XCode automatically, am i doing something wrong(leaking memory etc.) by setting it to nil manually myself? why or why not?

Thanks

**- MyProjAppDelegate.h**

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
@interface MyProjAppDelegate : NSObject <UIApplicationDelegate> {
    UIWindow *window;
    UIViewController *aboutViewController;
    UINavigationController *navController;
}

@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UIWindow *window;
@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UIViewController *aboutViewController;
@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UINavigationController *navController;
@end
```

**- MyProjAppDelegate.m**

```
#import "MyProjAppDelegate.h"
#import "AboutViewController.h"

@implementation MyProjAppDelegate
@synthesize window;
@synthesize aboutViewController;
@synthesize navController;

- (void)applicationDidFinishLaunching:(UIApplication *)application {    

    [window addSubview:aboutViewController.view];
    [window makeKeyAndVisible];

    [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:1.0 target:self selector:@selector(showMainView) userInfo:nil repeats:NO];
}

-(void)showMainView {
    [aboutViewController.view removeFromSuperview];
    self.aboutViewController = nil;

    [window addSubview:navController.view];
}

- (void)dealloc {
    [navController release];
    [aboutViewController release];
    [window release];
    [super dealloc];
}
@end
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> As the about view controller is loaded by XCode automatically, am i doing something wrong(leaking memory etc.) by setting it to nil manually myself?

No, you're not doing anything wrong, because you are using the property accessor method (`self.aboutViewController`) to set it to `nil`; the accessor will take care of the `release`. (And, you are correctly removing it from the superview *before* releasing it :-)

Comment: ok, so when i think from the memory management aspect, i am not the owner of the aboutViewController as i do not create it myself so i should not release it, or may be i'm the owner because XCode *creates it for me(inplace of me)* so i could release it, is this right?